# Regular expression needed for this pattern: point(latitude,longitude)

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to validate text that follows the pattern below:

- Must have the text "point(" at the beginning
- Must follow it by a Latitude numerical value with up to 5 decimal places (example: 42.12345)
- Must follow it by a comma ","
- Must follow it by a Longitude numerical value with up to 5 decimal places (example: -81.12345)
- Must follow it by a closing parentheses ")"

Matching example:

- point(42.12345,-81.12345)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily build your regex with a little bit of break-up here.

- To match `point(` at the beginning, use - `^point\(`
- To match a latitude or longitude numbers, use - `[-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?`
- And again, to match `)` at the end, use `\)$`.

For `[-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?`, here's an explanation: -

- `[-]?`  - matches an optional `negative (-)` sign at the starting (`? quantifier` at the end means 0 or 1)
- `\d+`   - matches one or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?`  - matches an optional `decimal`, followed by `one or more
  digits`. dot(.) is a special meta-character in Regex, so you need to escape it, if you want to match it.

Also, to limit your number of digits to `5`, you can use - `\d{1,5}` instead of `\d+`, which matches minimum 1 and maximum 5 digits.

`^(caret)` and `$(dollar)` anchors matches the beginning and end of the string.

So, here's your regex: -

```
^point\([-]?\d+(?:\.\d{1,5})?,[-]?\d+(?:\.\d{1,5})?\)$
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^point\(\-?\d+\.\d{1,5},\-?\d+\.\d{1,5}\)$
```

- Must have the text "point(" at the beginning: `^point\(`
- Must follow it by a Latitude numerical value with up to 5 decimal places (example: 42.12345): `\-?\d+\.\d{1,5}`
- Must follow it by a comma ",": `,`
- Must follow it by a Longitude numerical value with up to 5 decimal places (example: -81.12345): `\-?\d+\.\d{1,5}`
- Must follow it by a closing parentheses ")": `\)$`

The latitude and longitude logic can be further broken up like this.

- `\-?` = match on a negative sign if it exists (must escape with `\` because `-` has special meaning in RegEx)
- `\d+` = match one or more decimal characters (i.e. `0` through `9`)
- `\.` = match the period (`.` alone has special meaning, must escape it)
- `\d{1,5}` = match one to five decimal characters

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
point\((?<lat>-?\d+\.\d{1,5}),(?<long>-?\d+\.\d{1,5})\)
```

Try using a regex tool, like expresso: http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
^point\((\-?\d+(\.\d+)?),\s*(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)\)$
```